# How do I print a new line in the program for the user to type in their answer on?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, user-input

I am coding a Python dice game. I want the game to start when the user lets it.

So far I have this code:

```
number = random.randint(1, 6)

print("Do you want to roll the die?")
answer = input("Please type 'yes' or 'no': ")

dic = {"yes"}

while(True): 
    answer = input()
    if answer in dic:
        print("You have rolled: ", (number))
        break
    else:
        print("oh.")
```

But when the program runs, the user has to type "yes" in twice, for it to register it.

How do I skip the user having to type on the "Please type 'yes' or 'no': " line, so that they answer only once, on the line after it?

I have tried using print(), but I'm not sure where to put it so that it doesn't cause errors.

Thank you

Comment: Just remove the `input` block in 3rd line then. You are asking twice for input, once in 3rd line and after that inside `while` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is prompted twice because you're calling the `input` function twice. You only need to call it inside the loop.

```
number = random.randint(1, 6)
print("Do you want to roll the die?")
dic = {"yes"}
while(True): 
    answer = input("Please type 'yes' or 'no': ")
    if answer in dic:
        print("You have rolled: ", (number))
        break
    else:
        print("oh.")
```